# I am new to web scraping,

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I was sent some examples of past web scraping projects. I ran it on python and it didn't work because I didn't have the libraries installed. I figured out that I was able to download it on my MAC OS's terminal and used the command `pip install uszipcode`. My question is why did this work on my terminal and is there a way I could have installed the uszipcode package directly on python?

Also, any recommendations/tips, because I feel like the person I am researching for just threw all of this at me and did not really walk me through the proper steps.

Comment: The question is unclear.  Are you trying to understand why the `uszipcode` lib needed to be installed through the terminal instead of from within the python shell (REPL) itself?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

pip is a package installer for python.
You can use pip to install packages from the Python Package Index and other indexes.
If we need any python package we can install it via command prompt using the command
**pip install [package_name]**
You can also uninstall a package using the following command. 
**pip uninstall [package_name]**

Pip install is the most easiest way to install any package.
You need not search the internet or bother about the version of the package as everything will be taken care of by the pip command

**Pip install has several stages:
1) Identify the base requirements. The user supplied arguments are processed here.
2) Resolve dependencies. What will be installed is determined here.
3) Build wheels. All the dependencies that can be are built into wheels.
4) Install the packages (and uninstall anything being upgraded/replaced).**

There may be problems regarding dependencies when you are working with a lot of packages. pip install will take care of dependencies while intalling new pakcages.So that is a great help.

Since you are new it may be a bit overwhelming regarding installing packages or libraries via commands in command prompt but as you get used to it you will understand that it is much more easier than any other method.

If you want to know more about pip command then visit the following page
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/

My suggestion will be that don't feel afraid to try out new things and you will get used to it, so don't worry.If you have any doubts or errors you can always post them on stackoverflow , it is a great community. My friend you are not alone, so just explore your project with an open mind. You will learn and acquire all the knowledge you need as you go through it.